# Loading a UIImage in a UIImageView that is part of a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

So I have things nested like this in a nib:

```
UIViewController
|
|-UIView (container for some about text UILabel)
|    |
|    UILabel
|
UIScrollView (makes image scalable)
    |
    UIImageView
```

I'm trying to load the image of the UIImageView programmatically in another view controller, then pushing the new UIViewController onto a UINavigationController. Everything works fine, but when I assign the image, nothing appears on the new view.

So in a connectionDidFinishLoading: I do this:

```c
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
MyImageController* imageController = [[MyImageController alloc] init];
imageController.title = expandImage.title;
imageController.imageView.image = image;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:imageController animated:YES];
```

Nothing shows up besides what I designed in the nib. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these solution for your problem:

1.First of all, be sure that you get an image and you have an image data in the `imageData` variable.

2.most likely this solution is what you are looking for. declare a variable in the `MyImageController` of type `UIImage`, and set the propriety and synthesize for it, then in your `connectionDidFinishLoading` code, set the returned image to the variable that you declare, and in the `MyImageController` assign the variable to the `imageController.imageView`.

i hope that help you, and tell me what you got from these solution

good luck.

Comment: Nailed it! Can you explain why that worked? Is it something to do with the way things are loaded in the UIViewController?

Comment: because the `imageView` is not been initialized, the initilization is begning in the `viewDidLoad` as you know. you got that my friend !?